# Is there a first-order formula expressing this property?

Tags: logic, relations, predicate-logic, formal-languages

Suppose $R$ is a binary relation on $\{0,1\}^*$ (where $\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of all finite words over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$), and suppose that for all $x \in \{0,1\}^*$, the number of $y$ such that $x \mathrel{R}y$ is finite.

Is there a formula $\phi(x)$ in first-order logic (using only the relation $R$ and the lexicographic order on $\{0,1\}^*$) such that $\phi(x) \iff \text{there is an even number of } y \text{ such that } x \mathrel{R} y$?

Comment: I don't think there is. But I don't know of any argument that could be used to show this ... sorry

Comment: That's okay. In the course of trying to solve the problem from which this question arose, it became clear that if any such formula exists, it would be VERY complicated.

Comment: Your question is an interesting one, but it does not specify the context in which it arose, nor did you give your thoughts or attempts in solving it. Here on Math SE we do expect both of these (briefly at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such first-order formula. By contradiction, suppose there is a first-order formula $\varphi$ using only the relation $R$ and the lexicographic order $\leqslant_{lex}$ on $\{0,1\}^*$ such that $\varphi(x)$ is true if and only if
$$
\textit{ there is an even number of $y$ such that $x \mathrel{R} y$}.
$$
Let $R$ be the relation on $\{0,1\}^*$ defined as follows:
$$
x \mathrel{R} y \iff \text{$x = 0^n$, $y = 0^m$ and $m < n$}
$$
Observe that the restriction to $0^*$ of the lexicographic order is defined by 
$$ 
0^n \leqslant_{lex} 0^m \iff n \leqslant m,
$$ 
which is equivalent to $\neg (0^n \mathrel{R} 0^m)$. It follows that on $0^*$, any formula of $FO[R, \leqslant_{lex}]$  is equivalent to a formula of $FO[\leqslant_{lex}]$. Moreover $(0^*, \leqslant_{lex})$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N}, \leqslant)$ and the property 
$$
\textit{there is an even number of $y$ such that $0^n \mathrel{R} y$}
$$
simply means that $n$ is even. It follows that if $\varphi$ existed, then the subset of even numbers of $\mathbb{N}$ would be definable in $F0[\leqslant]$. But it is a well-known result that this is not the case. If you prefer a language theoretic argument, you could say that the language $(00)^+$ is not first-order definable since it is not star-free.